# Sharepoint 2013 not displaying correctly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My Sharepoint website is not diplaying correctly.
I have performed an iisreset and reboot but the issue remains.  Subsites are displaying correctly.

[image]

Any and all sugestions welcome.

Comment: try different browser, or clear browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Waqas.  Clearing the browser cache fixed the issue.

Comment: Clearing the cache is not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these if clearing the cache does not work.

1. Go to http://{problematic_site}/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx and make sure the master page settings and Alternate CSS Url are setup correctly.
2. Apply default master page like "seatle" and default styles and css in Alternate CSS Url.
3. Open the SharePoint Url in Chrome and inspect the Network traffic to make sure there are no 404, 500 or other errors. Check in console for any javascript error.
4. Check the master page and css settings on sub sites which are working and apply the same on the problematic site.

Answer (score 0):

So this happened to me today....my problem was I had accidentally allowed a retention policy to be set on my Themes Library.  So I checked the Recycle Bin, and restored them all.  Site rendered perfectly.